# Connecting to remote server with SSH keys

Tags: shell, terminal, rsync

I have been trying to figure out where I am going wrong for a few days now.

I am trying to set up a pair of SSH keys, so my computer can remotely connect to my web server and run a script without a password.

I have generated the SSH keys on my Mac and placed the public key on the server in the '.ssh' folder, then added this to the 'authorized_keys' file.

When I run my command through terminal, I get the following, asking for both a passphrase and the password still.

```
Christophers-MacBook-Pro:~ christopherdavies$ bash /Users/christopherdavies/Desktop/rsync/chrisdavies/chrisdavies.sh
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/christopherdavies/.ssh/id_rsa': 
chrisdavies@shell.host.co.uk's password:
```

Am I right to have placed the public key from my SSH keys pair on my Mac onto the server?

I am a bit lost here, so would really appreciate some advice. I am slowly learning, but feel I may be doing something blatantly obviously wrong...

Comment: If you want to load the key into your Mac's keystore, use `ssh-add` -- thereafter the "Enter passphrase for key" won't happen (within the same session). That you're still getting a passphrase prompt after, though, indicates that something's broken with the configuration. Could be bad file permissions, could be lots of things; StackOverflow isn't the right place to debug it. See [unix.se] for somewhere questions about SSH are on-topic even if they aren't programming-specific.

Comment: For example, [SSH failed public key authentication](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163570/ssh-failed-public-key-authentication) might be a good place to start. There are several other answered Q&A entries there digging into different causes -- [can't login to a remote machine with key](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/235565/cant-login-to-a-remote-machine-with-key) is one instance, [SSH login doesn't work using a key without password](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131882/ssh-login-doesnt-work-using-a-key-without-password) is another.

Comment: ...if you go through the different answered questions and build a question that describes how you checked for the failure modes that others had (using the guidance included in those questions' answers, or in the folks asking them describing how they got the logs they included to know how to enable verbose logging / what to check for / etc), the end result should be that you either solve the problem yourself or can ask a question that has everything needed for an answer included therein.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are off to a good start. Some things to check:

- make sure you stored the public key under .ssh/authorized_keys on the **same user** to which you intend to connect. In your case, it seems that your remote user is "chrisdavies", so it should be under ~chrisdavies/.ssh/autorized_keys.
- make sure **your script** connects to the remote server as "chrisdavies". You might want to check that because you are under a different user on your MacBook "christopherdavies".
- To troubleshoot, try to SSH to the remote server instead of running the script directly. If you run "ssh chrisdavies@ and it works without the password, you do not have connectivity issues, and you'll need to look into your script.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Note the guidance in the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) that questions that aren't "about programming [as defined in the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" should be closed, not answered; and the "unique to software development" criteria ANDed into others therein.